# check if azure-resourcegroup is already exists via terraform script

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How to check if azure Resource group is already exists via Terra-form script in azure, if not then create Terra-form should create it ?

check if azure-resourcegroup is already exists via terraform script

Comment: Terraform is declarative, not imperative.  When using Terraform you shouldn't need to check for existing resources because you are creating a set of resources that has the same life cycle.  You wouldn't normally be adding resources to "possibly" existing resource groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior. As you might already know, you have

```
terraform plan - used to validate your tf script
```

and

```
terraform apply - to apply the tf script changes
```

If you use terraform plan before you apply, and you are attempting to create a resource group that already exists, you will get the below message

> No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.
>
> This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
> configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
> actions need to be performed.

Incase you use terraform apply directly, you will see the below message

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

But, there will be no change to your resource.

Hope this helps.